# How to add some space between subexamples of expex?

Tags: linguistics, expex

I want to add some space between the sub-examples generated with package [`expex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/expex). Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{%
  belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex,%
  aboveglftskip=-0.5ex%
}

\begin{document}
\pex
\a\begingl
\gla abcd//
\glb efgh//
\glft Add extra space after this.//
\endgl
\a\begingl
\gla abcd//
\glb efgh//
\glft No extra space after this.//
\endgl
\xe

\lipsum[1-1]

\pex
\a\begingl
\gla abcd//
\glb efgh//
\glft Add extra space after this.//
\endgl
\a\begingl
\gla abcd//
\glb efgh//
\glft No extra space after this.//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the option `interpartskip=<length>` in `lingset{...}` to set a global option or use     `\pex[interpartskip=<length>]` in a specific example.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{%
    belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex,%
    aboveglftskip=-0.5ex,%
    interpartskip=6ex % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

\begin{document}

    \pex
    \a\begingl
    \gla abcd//
    \glb efgh//
    \glft Add extra space after this.//
    \endgl
    \a\begingl
    \gla abcd//
    \glb efgh//
    \glft No extra space after this.//
    \endgl
    \xe
    
    \lipsum[1-1]
    
    \pex
    \a\begingl
    \gla abcd//
    \glb efgh//
    \glft Add extra space after this.//
    \endgl
    \a\begingl
    \gla abcd//
    \glb efgh//
    \glft No extra space after this.//
    \endgl
    \xe
\end{document}
```

Using `expex.sty    5/1/2017 v5.1b`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works as expected.